# Interface-Based Projections the getter method giving exception if the return type is java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using the spring boot strater 2.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT with Spirng JPA. I need to used some complex SQL with group by some I am using the native query with interface based projection, I am able retrived all the fields but getting exception for the return type of `java.sql.Timestamp`

Example : 
My Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "trade")
public class Trade {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "trade_id")
private long tradeId;

@Column(name = "symbol")
private String symbol;

@Column(name = "exchange")
private String exchange;

@Column(name = "segment")
private String segment;

@Column(name = "clinet_trade_id")
private long clientTradeId;

@Column(name = "order_id")
private long orderId;

@Column(name = "price")
private double price;

@Column(name = "sell_type")
private String tradeType;

@Column(name = "quantity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "trade_date_time")
private Timestamp tradeDateTime;
}
```

The repository interface with the projection interface

```
@Repository("TradeRepository")
public interface TradeRepository extends JpaRepository<Trade, Long> {


// projection

//https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections
//Interface-based Projections
//https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections

@Query(value = "select symbol,date(trade_date_time) as trade_date_time , sum(quantity) as quantity , sum(quantity*price) as price  from trade where sell_type ='sell' \n" + 
        "and trader_date > ?1  and trader_date < ?2 and user_id= ?3 " + 
        "group by symbol, date(trade_date_time) " + 
        "order by symbol, date(trade_date_time) ", nativeQuery = true)
 public List<TradeView> findByNativeQuery(Timestamp fromdate, Timestamp toDate, int userId);

public static interface TradeView {
     public String getSymbol();
     public Timestamp getTradeDateTime();
     public int getQuantity();
     public double getPrice();
  }


}
```

Here I am getting exception for the method `getTradeDateTime()`

Excaption trace

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Projection type must be an interface!
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:118)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory.createProjection(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.projection.SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory.createProjection(SpelAwareProxyProjectionFactory.java:45)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.getProjection(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProjectingMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProjectingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.ProxyProjectionFactory$TargetAwareMethodInterceptor.invoke(ProxyProjectionFactory.java:245)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy123.getTradeDateTime(Unknown Source)
at org.cet.stockAnalysis.repository.TradeRepositoryTest.findAllSaleTradeByDateTest(TradeRepositoryTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Can some one guide me what can be done, I have one solution is to change the DB column name to match with entity filed name, But I feel that is not right not, there must be some solution to this.

Debug screen shot

[image]

Note :I am getting the exception when calling the getter method to read the value and at that time also it is going to to ProxyProjectionFactory line number 100 and at that time the type id java.sql.Timestamp and ginving the exception

Scren shot

[image]

The Junit test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class TradeRepositoryTest {

@Autowired
TradeRepository tradeRepository;

@Test
public void findAllSaleTradeByDateTest() {
    Date fromdate = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.FEBRUARY, 1).getTime();
    Date todate = new GregorianCalendar(2019, Calendar.MARCH, 31).getTime();

    Timestamp fromTimestamp= new Timestamp(fromdate.getTime());
    Timestamp toTimestamp= new Timestamp(todate.getTime());

    User user = new User();
    user.setId(1);
    List<TradeView> tradeviews =tradeRepository.findByNativeQuery(fromTimestamp, toTimestamp, 1);
    System.out.println(tradeviews.get(0).getSymbol());
    System.out.println(tradeviews.get(0).getPrice());
    System.out.println(tradeviews.get(0).getTradeDateTime() +" >>>>>> ");
    System.out.println(tradeviews.get(0).getQuantity());


    assertNotNull(tradeviews);
}
```

}

Edit:

With the suggestion of Simon, I change the interface return type to java.sql.Date form java.sql.Timestamp and it's work fine as my native sql return type was date, because of date funtion was used

Hence chnaging the question title and details

Comment: use `as tradeDateTime` in your query. You are using SQL and not a JPQL hence it will do a `getObject("name-of-property")` to obtain the value from the JDBC resultset. There is no other way. Unless you use a projection for the `Trade` entity instead.

Comment: Yes I have tried the same and it is giving exception(Projection type must be an interface!) mention at end of question

Comment: Changing the name of the method will have no effeect, nor should you be messing around with the return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply us aliases the match the names in your interface. Don't use _ but tradeDateTime:

```
@Query(value = "select symbol, date(trade_date_time) as tradeDateTime, sum(quantity) as quantity , sum(quantity*price) as price  from trade where sell_type ='sell' \n" + 
    "and trader_date > ?1  and trader_date < ?2 and user_id= ?3 " + 
    "group by symbol, date(trade_date_time) " + 
    "order by symbol, date(trade_date_time) ", nativeQuery = true)
```

Reason: The column mapping in your entity is not taken to account when using native queries and interface projection.

*Also make sure that you have the correct return types the interface!*

Comment: Yes I have tried the same and it is giving exception(Projection type must be an interface!) mention at end of question

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint in ProxyProjectionFactory on line 100 to see what type comes in

Comment: The type is "interface org.cet.stockAnalysis.repository.TradeRepository$TradeView" and the source the key "tradeDateTime" screen shot added to Q.

Comment: Can you try to extract this interface to it's own file and not a nested interface in the repository?

Comment: Yes moved the interface to a file and got Same error, "Projection type must be an interface"

Comment: One things to be noted, I am getting the exception when calling the getter method to read the value and at that time also it is going to to ProxyProjectionFactory line number 100 and at that time the type id java.sql.Timestamp and ginving the exception

Comment: Can you show the code of findAllSaleTradeByDateTest

Comment: Stupid idea can you try to return a java.sql.Date instead of the Timestamp

Comment: Yes the it works, I change the type to java.sql.Date, still not clear what the issues with java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: The exception is very much misleading. But I assume that if the type of the result set does not match the return type defined in the interface there is a problem. I added a hint to my answer. I would appreciate it if you could mark it as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: My Trade Entity class as you can see in Q has Timestamp not the java.sql.Date, from begning I am using the same return type in both Entity class and projection interface. Now also the Entity class has the type Timestamp  and it is working, I feel it is geeting error on use of java.sql.TImestamp

Comment: No you get me wrong. The return type of the SQL query result set is date because your are calling the date function: date(trade_date_time)  So the interface also needs Date

Comment: Yes got it Thanks a lot, so the interface return type should match with Query retrun type not with the Entity type. I was matching this with my entity type